Need to use VBA to automate add/deduct function (based on a unique identifier) to arrive at a monthly closing balance

A table showing opening balance/ add/ deduct transactions during the month and closing balance
Hi all;
Would like to ask for some pointers on how to automate the steps shown below using VBA.
Please read in conjunction with the table above.
Every month, I need to manually:

from the opening balance (row #4 & 5) and based on the respective Sales Order (SO#) inside Column C which acts as a unique identifier,
match each transactions against the respective SO# shown inside Column C (from row# 8 to 14),

to arrive at the closing balance for each Sales Order (SO#) shown inside row #17 to 20.
Eg; in Mar2024;
Using SO# A1234, I need to start from opening balance (QTY 10) and deduct total 9pcs (-4-5) to arrive at closing balance Qty 1.
This needs to be repeated for the rest of the SO# as well.
For SO# A5678, I need to add net Qty 11 (+3+10-2) on top of the opening balance of 16 to arrive at closing balance 27.
For SO# B3456, I need to add 23. Since this is a new SO#, VBA should be smart enough to add this row as part of closing balance (Qty 23) for Mar2024.
For SO# Z6789, I need to deduct 13. But since this SO# does not existed inside the opening balance, then, VBA should be smart enough to add this row as part of closing balance for Mar2024 (albeit a negative QTY -13).
As my data set runs into tens of thousands, needless to say - this is very time consuming indeed.
How to do this inside VBA? What concept I need to learn up?
How to automate this task inside VBA?
What concepts that i need to learn up?

I know you said VBA, but all you really need is to use a pivot table. Simply put your data into a single table (the opening and the transactions all together) like so:



Month
QTY
SO#
Amount
Extended Amount




Mar-24
10
A1234
1,2
12


Mar-24
16
A5678
1,5
24


Mar-24
-4
A1234
1,2
-4,8


Mar-24
3
A5678
1,5
4,5


Mar-24
-5
A1234
1,2
-6


Mar-24
10
A5678
1,5
15


Mar-24
23
B3456
2,3
52,9


Mar-24
-13
Z6789
1,4
-18,2


Mar-24
-2
A5678
1,5
-3



Then create a pivot table from this range, put "Month", "SO#" and "Amount" into Rows and the rest of the fields into Values.
Then go to PivotTable Tools -> Design -> Report Layout -> Show in Tabular Form and Design -> Subtotals -> Do Not Show Subtotals
This is the result:

